# lsmeans (R): Adjust for multiple comparisons with interaction terms

Tags: r, interaction, post-hoc, lsmeans

I have a lsmeans problem in R. I want to do a post-hoc analysis of an interaction, similar to examples provided in the lsmeans documentation.

I am puzzled by the fact that the p-values are the same whether I use

```
warp.lm <- lm(breaks ~ wool * tension, data = warpbreaks)
```

(A):

```
lsmeans(warp.lm, list(pairwise ~ wool|tension, pairwise ~ tension|wool))
```

or
(B):

```
lsmeans(warp.lm, list(pairwise ~ wool|tension))
```

Should the p-values not be higher in the case of (A) than (B)? (A) makes 9 post-hoc comparisons, (B) only 3.

Can I be sure that (A) is adjusted for all 9 comparisons?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by properly? I suggest using the lsmeans function first without the left-hand side , then use `pairs` to get the contrasts you want. Read the vignette "using-lsmeans" for a lt of examples and discussion.

Comment: @rvl Sorry this wasn't clear. For both commands you get the same p-values. 
tension = L:
 contrast  estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 A - B    16.333333 5.157299 48   3.167  0.0027

tension = M:
 A - B    -4.777778 5.157299 48  -0.926  0.3589

tension = H:
 A - B     5.777778 5.157299 48   1.120  0.2682

Should the p-values not be higher after the first command than the second? 
There are more comparisons to be made after the first command.

I tried the "pairs" route but the results are the same as "pairwise".

Comment: The p-value adjustments are applied to each grouping separately. If you want one adjustment for the whole set of comparisons, you'll need to do custom contrasts.

Comment: I have an answer suggestion to post, but I can't post it because the question was put on hold. If it can be taken off hold, I'll post it.

Comment: @Scortchi Could you please take the question off hold so that rvl could answer it? I have edited it so hopefully you will find it clearer. Thank you.

Comment: @Sam: I have done - thanks for editing it. (Note that once you edit a question it'll automatically join a review queue for re-opening.) But it's still as clear as mud to anyone unfamiliar with R's `lsmeans` package & I'd be grateful if you'd edit it further to explain what statistical analysis you're trying to carry out, & why the results are unexpected.

Comment: @rvl: I've re-opened this question so you can answer - do please explain the underlying statistical issues as well as illustrating the analysis with `lsmeans`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both of the `lsmeans` statements you show generate **lists** of `lsmobj`s, and each element of those lists is handled separately. If you want to incorporate an overall adjustment for two or more lists combined, it is technical and it takes a bit of work.

First, save the list:

```
lsmlist = lsmeans(warp.lm, list(pairwise ~ wool|tension, 
                  pairwise ~ tension|wool))
```

This creates a list of 4 `lsmobj`s (originally two lists of two)

```
> names(lsmlist)
[1] "lsmeans of wool | tension"                          
[2] "pairwise differences of contrast, tension | tension"
[3] "lsmeans of tension | wool"                          
[4] "pairwise differences of contrast, wool | wool"
```

The user wants to combine the three comparisons in `lsmlist[[2]]` with the six in `lsmlist[[4]]` and have an overall multiplicity adjustment for those 9 comparisons.

To start, create a new `lsmobj` from one of the results, and fix it up.

```
mydiffs = lsmlist[[4]]
```

First, bind together the linear functions for the two sets of comparisons:

```
mydiffs@linfct = rbind(lsmlist[[2]]@linfct, lsmlist[[4]]@linfct)
```

We also need to define the `grid` slot, which defines the factors associated with each linear function. To make it simple, I just define a factor named `contrast` with 9 levels for the 9 contrasts (something fancier could be done here).

```
mydiffs@grid = data.frame(contrast = 1:9)
```

Finally, fix up the auxiliary info that does the bookkeeping. We now use our new `contrast` factor as the only variable, with no "by" variables. For the combined family of 9 contrasts, the Tukey adjustment makes no sense so we use the multivariate $t$ (`"mvt"`) method:

```
mydiffs = update(mydiffs, pri.vars = "contrast", by.vars = NULL,
                 adjust="mvt")
```

Now, we can look at the resulting summary:

```
> mydiffs

 contrast   estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
        1 16.3333333 5.157299 48   3.167  0.0205
        2 -4.7777778 5.157299 48  -0.926  0.9119
        3  5.7777778 5.157299 48   1.120  0.8258
        4 20.5555556 5.157299 48   3.986  0.0019
        5 20.0000000 5.157299 48   3.878  0.0026
        6 -0.5555556 5.157299 48  -0.108  1.0000
        7 -0.5555556 5.157299 48  -0.108  1.0000
        8  9.4444444 5.157299 48   1.831  0.3796
        9 10.0000000 5.157299 48   1.939  0.3190

P value adjustment: mvt method for 9 tests
```

I could consider adding a feature for combining pieces of `lsm.list` objects, but it is not straightforward -- primarily because of complications in obtaining meaningful labels for the results (the `grid` part). It is also a problem that different users expect different defaults.

Comment: fantastic answers as always.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, this is brilliant! If there could be a warning message incorporated that would be useful, I think. This default does produce a lot of false positives.

Comment: Please note -- I posted a question related to this -- http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167097/its-all-in-the-family-but-do-we-include-the-in-laws-too

Answer (score 9):

### Provision in upcoming version of **lsmeans**

The next update of **lsmeans** (2.20 or later) will include an `rbind` method for `ref.grid` and `lsmobj` objects. It makes it easy to combine two or ore objects into one family, and defaults to the `"mvt"` adjustment method. Here is the present example:

```
> w.t <- pairs(lsmeans(warp.lm, ~ wool | tension))
> t.w <- pairs(lsmeans(warp.lm, ~ tension | wool))

> rbind(w.t, t.w)
 tension wool contrast   estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 L       .    A - B    16.3333333 5.157299 48   3.167  0.0203
 M       .    A - B    -4.7777778 5.157299 48  -0.926  0.9119
 H       .    A - B     5.7777778 5.157299 48   1.120  0.8258
 .       A    L - M    20.5555556 5.157299 48   3.986  0.0018
 .       A    L - H    20.0000000 5.157299 48   3.878  0.0027
 .       A    M - H    -0.5555556 5.157299 48  -0.108  1.0000
 .       B    L - M    -0.5555556 5.157299 48  -0.108  1.0000
 .       B    L - H     9.4444444 5.157299 48   1.831  0.3793
 .       B    M - H    10.0000000 5.157299 48   1.939  0.3191

P value adjustment: mvt method for 9 tests
```

If you do specify Tukey instead of mvt, it comes fairly close to the same result:

```
> test(rbind(w.t, t.w), adjust = "tukey")
 tension wool contrast   estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 L       .    A - B    16.3333333 5.157299 48   3.167  0.0196
 M       .    A - B    -4.7777778 5.157299 48  -0.926  0.8683
 H       .    A - B     5.7777778 5.157299 48   1.120  0.7727
 .       A    L - M    20.5555556 5.157299 48   3.986  0.0018
 .       A    L - H    20.0000000 5.157299 48   3.878  0.0026
 .       A    M - H    -0.5555556 5.157299 48  -0.108  0.9999
 .       B    L - M    -0.5555556 5.157299 48  -0.108  0.9999
 .       B    L - H     9.4444444 5.157299 48   1.831  0.3467
 .       B    M - H    10.0000000 5.157299 48   1.939  0.2922

P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4.772 estimates
```

The curiously fractional family size results from ${4.772 \choose 2} = 9$.